# Passing tuples to function parameters

Tags: scala

Suppose I have this code:

```
def a(x:Int,y:Int):Int = x+y

def b:(Int,Int) = (1,2)
```

and I would like to accomplish:

```
  a(b)
```

What is the proper way of doing this? Also are there more efficient ways of calling a predefined multi-parameter function - in my case 8 - with the results of another function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about:

```
scala> (a _).tupled(b)
res0: Int = 3
```

- a is a method. `a _` gives you a partially applied function.
- [Function2.tupled](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Function2@tupled:%28%28T1,T2%29%29=%3ER) creates a tupled version from your function.

Comment: BTW, a question to the experts, is this efficient?

Comment: overhead per call: one instance creation (Function2) and a call on 'tupled'. measure it for your use case! you can use JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness) to check. there is also a sbt plugin: https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh