# Scala map parameter inconsistency

Tags: scala

Let's say I have this method

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements: List = List(1, 2, 3)
  StructType(elements map function)
}
```

where function is

```
def function(listEle: Int): StructField = {
  // doesn't matter what happens here
}
```

This code works.

How do I call "function" if I added more parameters to it? e.g.

```
def function(listEle: Int, anotherParam1: Int, anotherParam2: Int): StructField = {
  //
}
```

I tried

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements: List = List(1, 2, 3)
  StructType(elements map function(4, 5))
}
```

but it complains that the method is missing a parameter bc function expects 3 inputs. However, I want to keep this way of calling "elements map function" to return a StructType.

Comment: This should give you an idea: [`(someFunc _).tupled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655732/223424) will accept a tuple of parameters of `someFunc` as a single parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but the closest one to your example is;

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements: List = List(1, 2, 3)
  StructType(elements.map(function(_, 4, 5)))
}
```

Comment: it now complains "type mismatch" as the "_" is apparently a StructField instead of an int

Comment: It was a syntax error relating to parsing `elements map f(_` in the wrong order. Best to be specific with `elements.map(f(_` - answer corrected

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your first example is implicitly passing the callback parameter provided by `map` to your `function` callback.

If you write it in the following form, you can easily see how you could achieve your desired result:

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements = Seq(1, 2, 3)
  StructType(elements.map(element => function(element)))
}
```

Changed code for more parameters:

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements = Seq((1, 11, 111), (2, 22, 222), (3, 33, 333))
  StructType(elements.map(element => function(element._1, element._2, element._3)))
}
```

Other example:

```
def mapFunction(): StructType = {
  val elements = Seq(1, 2, 3)
  val second = 10
  val third = 100
  StructType(elements.map(element => function(element, second, third)))
}
```